# Web3 ExtraDataLength Error on Optimism using python

Tags: python, web3py

ERROR - The field extraData is 97 bytes, but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA chain. Refer http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority for more details. The full extraData is: HexBytes('...')

The error happens on this line of code

`tx = uniswap.close_position(TOKEN_ID)`

Here is the full file. As you can see I tried adding the middleware but same error message still.

```
from uniswap import Uniswap
import web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

TOKEN_ID = 240756

w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider('https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/{MY_ID}'))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

address = ""       
private_key = ""  
version = 3                       
provider = "https://optimism-mainnet.infura.io/v3/{MY_ID}"    
uniswap = Uniswap(address=address, private_key=private_key, version=version, provider=provider)

tx = uniswap.close_position(TOKEN_ID)
print(tx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error with my request, and found your post.

I tried injecting the geth POA middleware as you were doing and it worked for me. However, I was connecting via Alchemy rather than Infura.

Here's my code if you want to try to replicate:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(f"https://opt-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{ALCHEMY_KEY}"))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

block_num = w3.eth.blockNumber
block = w3.eth.getBlock(block_num, True)
```